# Optimal way to get a string or char* into an istream?

Tags: c++, stream

What is the most optimal way to get a string or char* pointer into an istream.

I want to do the following

```
std::string a = "abc..";

//I know this can be done, not sure if this is most efficient
// and not sure about char*    pointers
std::istringstream istr (a);
...
foo (istr); 


void foo(std::istream& is) {

}
```

Comment: Sorry; it's not entirely clear what you're asking here. Do you want to be able to access a string as if it were a stream? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i should note that your code is invalid. you cannot construct an istream from an istringstream. what do you think it should do (note, streams can't be copied).

Comment: edited my use case and I think i could use up_cast if i wanted to use istringstream to istream

Answer (score 28):

This will work:

```
 std::istringstream is("abc...");
```

And since istringstream is a istream, you will be able to use your is object as an istream.

Comment: This seems to be the obvious answer - or is the OP really asking something else?

Comment: I was also looking for this and didn't know it would be so easy. streams are hard if you don't know them :)

Comment: Doesn't this make a copy of the string, until C++20? If so, it depends on what the asker means by "optimal".

Answer (score 28):

If you want to construct an istringstream from it, a char* up to the null character, or all the stuff from an std::string:

```
istringstream str(ptr); // char*
istringstream str(other_str); // std::string
```

If you talk about wanting a raw pointer into the buffer of an istream, you can't do it. Streams get their data on-demand if they need them either from files, terminals or else, optionally buffering their stuff (well, not exactly right. You can use a `strstream`, which accepts a raw pointer and reads/writes directly from that. But it's a deprecated class - don't use it. I'm lucky i've never done so). If all you want is something you can use somewhat like a pointer, you can use streambuf iterators. They are not really pointers though, so you can't subtract `end` from `begin` and other stuffs:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(one_istream), end;
while(begin != end)
    std::cout << *begin++;
```

If you talk about getting a string out of what was written into a stringstream, you can use `ostringstream::str`:

```
ostringstream o;
o << "This is a number: " << 42;
std::string str = o.str(); // str == "This is a number: 42"
```

Otherwise, you can only generally *read* stuff from an `istream`. You need an `ostream`, then you can do

```
stream.write(ptr, N);
stream.write(ptr.c_str(), ptr.c_str() + ptr.size());
```

to write exactly N characters from the bytes that str points to. You can write it into the stream using `<<` too. It will write everything up to the null character, or everything from an std::string, but will respect formatting flags, like the field width:

```
stream << ptr; // char*
stream << other_str; // everything from std::string
```